# PHP - Storing image link in database and display on different pages (Localhost)

Tags: php, database, localhost

SO! uhh, its not letting me post normally, sorry about the formatting im new! and confused ha! if anyone can help me with the below request that would be amazing! I've been struggling for the past 3 days!!

I'm going to try keep this as simple as possible to understand.

Heres what I'm trying to do:

Users can have profile pictures, they upload the image, the image goes to their file (named after their username) and the link of the image gets stored in the database.

My problem:

I'm running on localhost, and for some reason I can't display the picture on all pages.
    (e.g. works on Profile page, doesn't work in index page.)
    Profile page link = sessions/settings/profile
    Index = sessions/index
    User profiles = sessions/users/

The code I'm using to store this is:

```
    $uploadDir = '../../users/' .$username. "/";
```

(This work only on profile)

What I've tried:

```
    $uploadDir = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . 'dir/sessions/users/'  .$username.  "/";
```

(this doesn't execute) And a few other obvious methods.

Sorry about it being so broad with the question, hope I explained it properly!

Comment: Do you want picture's folder or picture URL ?

Comment: I'm wondering is there a way for the link to work on all pages? It stores in the database as ../../users/username/image.png so it doesn't load on index pages or any other page thats not in settings directory because the (../../) is backing out to folders? If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save only filename and get directory from your code, because it could change frequently.

So, get filename and put in database, only, i.e, `username.png` and, when getting users' avatar, concatenate full url to it, including HOST, and folders. Something like this:

```
$user_avatar_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/path/to/user_avatar/" + username.png;
```

Note: Check if `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]` has last backslash. If you're using HTTPS protocol, then create if statement using `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`

Full URL is the best practice, instead of using relative dir.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$uploadDir = "$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']" . '/users/' .$username. "/";
```

Comment: The link saves as /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dir/sessions/users/username/1kgbXdRu.jpeg

This doesn't display the image on any page now, the link appears as in posted images: 

http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dir/sessions/users/username/1kgbXdRu.jpeg

Comment: Try replacing $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] with $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']